# Проблема с ConvertAll

Tags: .net, pascalabc.net

Возникла такая проблема

У меня есть `List<T>` и там числа но в формате `string` и мне их нужно в формат `double`

И я пытаюсь применить метод ConvertAll но к сожалению не конвертируется

```
var lst1:=new List<string>;//Список для хранения значений
var lst2:=new List<double>;//Список для хранения значений
lst2:=lst1.ConvertAll(Converter<string,double>);
```

Компилятор находит ошибки.

Хотя я указываю сначала тип который в данный момент`<TInput>` он у меня string и тип который я хочу получить `<TOutput>` а именно double

Comment: "не конвертируется" - а что?

Comment: Не получается получить конвертированный список с <double>

Comment: а что получается?

Comment: PascalABC язык под платформу .NET, поэтому добавляйте этот тег, чтобы дотнетчики обращали внимание на ваши вопросы. А тег `winforms` в данном случае не нужен, т. к. в вопросе нет ничего про формы.

Comment: Просто сами числа в формате string,а нужно в double чтобы найти минимум среди этих чисел

Но мне главное сделать правильно ConvertAll который не корректно работает почему-то

Comment: так что за ошибки-то?

Answer (score 0):

Путём подсказки и доработки получилось нужное решение

```
lst2:=lst1.ConvertAll(x -> Convert.ToDouble(x));
```

Но если сделать так:

```
lst2:=lst1.ConvertAll(x -> StrToFloat(x));
```

то вылетает исключение

Поэтому использовать лучше 1-ый верхний вариант